# pass a text field to be a field in a linked php file in order to create a parameter

Tags: php, hyperlink, field

I have a form on a page which uploads a file. This form also has a 'ship_id' field to identify which record the file belongs to. Basically I need to pass the 'ship_id' field into 'upload_update.php' so that the link to 'update_ship.php' has two parameters, the name of the ship (which works perfectly well) AND the 'ship_id' which isn't working.... not sure how to achieve this.

Many thanks

Main form:

```
<form action="upload_update.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
  <input name="ship_id" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['ship_id']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

upload_update.php file:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Image succsefuly uploaded. " . "<br>" . "<br>";
    ?>
            <a href="update_ship.php?file_name=<?php echo$_FILES["file"]["name"] ?>&amp;ship_id=<?php echo $_GET['ship_id']; ?>">Click Hereto return to Add Ship page</a>
<?php


    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../images/ships/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: where do you get the 'ship_id' from?

Comment: ship_id is passed to the first form as a URL paramater from its linking page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $_GET['ship_id'] you get the field as a GET parameter.

Then you submit it in the form as a POST parameter. So in the upload_update.php you should get it with

```
$_POST['ship_id']
```

Also you might consider sending it in the form as a hidden field:

```
<input name="ship_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['ship_id']; ?>" />
```

Comment: You're amazing! I had the ship_id hidden, but put it as text to help track it through. Thank you for that help x